# The best way to create an activity that partially overlay the parent

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

Immagine a blank activity. If you swipe from left to right another activity (I think) comes in partially covering the parent.

I would like to recreate this effect:
[image]
[image]

I'm new to android programming and the only thing that i could think to do that is to use fragment in some strange way.

Since i don't know how to call this "function" i didn't manage to find a lot on the web.

So, is there a method to easly accomplish this? Can you give me any info on where to start e what to search for to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: "If you swipe from left to right another activity (I think) comes in partially covering the parent" -- no. That is all one activity. "is there a method to easly accomplish this?" -- [use `DrawerLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html).

Comment: You can achieve that easily in Android Studio, File->New->Activity->Navigation Drawer Activity

Comment: Well, that was fast! i'll try that. (I just thought they were the same activity because when i press back it goes back to the map)

Comment: Note that an Activity, by definition, occupies the entire screen. To do this, you need to use Fragments instead. In particular, a Fragment with a DrawerLayout..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using the DrawerLayout. You can find a lot of help online about using DrawerLayouts, but this link is how I learned and it helped me so much:

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer